# HTTPS on Nodejitsu using Express

Tags: node.js, express, nodejitsu, node-http-proxy

Okay. I have an app on express which also uses Socket.io and works fine via HTTP. However, now I have to move to HTTPS. Nodejitsu provide a lot of documentation on this. They suggest to use node-http-proxy (https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). Fine!

From the code for HTTP:

```
var server = http.createServer(app) // app is an Express instance
server.listen(config.port,config.hostip) // config.port is 80 for localhost and 3000 for Nodejitsu, config.hostip is 127.0.0.1 for localhost and 0.0.0.0 for Nodejitsu
```

I got this:

```
var server = http.createServer(app)
var options = {
  https: {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/ssl/privatekey.pem", 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/ssl/certificate.pem", 'utf8')
  }
}
httpProxy.createServer(config.port, config.hostip, options).listen(3001,config.hostip)
var proxy = new httpProxy.HttpProxy({
  target: {
    host: config.hostip, 
    port: config.port
  }
})
https.createServer(options.https, function (req, res) {
  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res)
}).listen(3002,config.hostip)
server.listen(config.port,config.hostip)
```

When I finally deploy (no errors during deployment), I visit the page and see 502 error Socket hang up. OK, I might doing something wrong, so I just copy and paste the example from https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy "Proxying to HTTP from HTTPS" to check if it works. But it doesn't - 502 error.

It works fine on my localhost though. I have also tried to launch standalone HTTPS server without node-https-proxy, but no luck. Please help, I cannot solve this for weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found by myself. Nodejitsu offers SSL by default, just visit your site via HTTPS://. For custom domains to apply SSL certs you need to subscribe for Business Plan.